# Cisco Switch Minicom, putty, picocom doesn't work

Tags: networking, drivers, usb-modem, serial-port, cisco

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm connected with a Cisco switch Catalyst 2950 through a Serial(RS232) to USB console cable. The name of my serial port is ttyUSB0 according to following command result:

> dmesg
>
> [ 2545.722631] ch341 3-2:1.0: device disconnected
>   [ 2547.010185] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
>   [ 2547.139087] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523
>   [ 2547.139097] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
>   [ 2547.139102] usb 3-2: Product: USB2.0-Ser!
>   [ 2547.139754] ch341 3-2:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
>   [ 2547.140802] usb 3-2: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0

I configured minicom as follows:

```
| A -    Serial Device      : /dev/ttyUSB0                              |
| B - Lockfile Location     : /var/lock                                 |
| C -   Callin Program      : cisco                                     |
| D -  Callout Program      :                                           |
| E -    Bps/Par/Bits       : 9600 8N1                                  |
| F - Hardware Flow Control : No                                        |
| G - Software Flow Control : No
```

I lunched that command, before starting minicom, to start ftdi_sio driver:

> sudo modprobe ftdi_sio
>   lsmod | grep ftd
>
> ```
>  ftdi_sio      53248 0  
>  usbserial     53248 2 ch341,ftdi_sio
> ```

The problem is that i don't get any output, just that:

> Welcome to minicom 2.7
>
> OPTIONS: I18n
>   Compiled on Jan  1 2014, 17:13:19.
>   Port /dev/ttyUSB0, 10:06:48
>
> Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
>
> CTRL-A Z for help | 9600 8N1 | NOR | Minicom 2.7 | VT102 | Offline | ttyUSB0

That's it. If i lunch picocom i also get no output:

> sudo picocom -l /dev/ttyUSB0
>   picocom v1.7
>
> port is        : /dev/ttyUSB0
>   flowcontrol    : none 
>   baudrate is    : 9600 
>   parity is      : none
>   databits are   : 8
>   escape is      : C-a
>   local echo is  : no
>   noinit is      : no
>   noreset is     : no 
>   nolock is      : yes
>   send_cmd is    : sz -vv
>   receive_cmd is : rz -vv
>   imap is        :
>   omap is        :
>   emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,
>
> Terminal ready

If I lunch putty it's the same, no output. I tried to access to Switch Console using putty on windows and everything works perfect. On Ubuntu I also tried to connect the cable on 2.0 and 3.0 USB ports without good results.

I really don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I followed this guide to solve my problem:
http://blog.xentoo.info/2015/12/31/ubuntu-14-04-and-usb-to-serial-ch341-chinese-device-from-ebay/